# Make a caeser cipher

Tags: code-golf

I love my encryption but I need a program that is dedicated to making a caeser cipher. It will take an input string and will output a ciphered text with the number to decode it. The number can be made whatever you want

The shortest code wins!

Comment: I wanted to borrow some code from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher but these are a bit large

Comment: I've voted to close as "too broad", due to the lack of specifics. This leaves glaring loopholes (as can be seen by current answers) and renders the challenge trivial/uninteresting.

Comment: I went for unclear, but w/e. Any close reason will do.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think it's pretty clear what he's asking.

Answer (score 6):

## Golfscript, 1 character

```
0
```

Outputs the input string rotated by 0 characters, plus the digit `0` to show how to decode it.

(*sorry, I couldn't resist*)

Comment: also powershell [0-9], for letters 'a'

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby - 12

This was my first idea.

```
puts gets+?0
```

I see Doorknob posted an answer as I'm typing this, similar to my next idea:

### CJam - 4

```
q0pp
```

Both of these shift by 0.

This might not count, because I haven't actually released the interpreter yet, but my golfing language KSFTgolf can do it like this:

```
0
```

<s>That's zero bytes</s>. It takes a byte to print the zero

Here are more:

### Python 2 - 21

```
print raw_input()+"0"
```

### Python 3 - 18

```
print(input()+"0")
```

### Perl 5 - 10

```
print<>.0;
```

Comment: Your Ruby solution would output quotes around the string (inspect it), making it invalid. You have to use `puts` or `$><<` instead. (You could also save a character by replacing `"0"` with `?0`.)

Comment: @Doorknob Is that invalid? I don't think it says so in the question.

Comment: @Doorknob Meh, I changed it anyway